# How do I multiply matrices in PyTorch?

Tags: python, matrix, pytorch, matrix-multiplication

With numpy, I can do a simple matrix multiplication like this:

```
a = numpy.ones((3, 2))
b = numpy.ones((2, 1))
result = a.dot(b)
```

However, this does not work with PyTorch:

```
a = torch.ones((3, 2))
b = torch.ones((2, 1))
result = torch.dot(a, b)
```

This code throws the following error:

> RuntimeError: 1D tensors expected, but got 2D and 2D tensors

How do I perform matrix multiplication in PyTorch?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Use [`torch.mm`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.mm.html):

```
torch.mm(a, b)
```

`torch.dot()` behaves differently to `np.dot()`. There's been some discussion about what would be desirable [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/138). Specifically, `torch.dot()` treats both `a` and `b` as 1D vectors (irrespective of their original shape) and computes their inner product. The error is thrown because this behaviour makes your `a` a vector of length 6 and your `b` a vector of length 2; hence their inner product can't be computed. For matrix multiplication in PyTorch, use `torch.mm()`. Numpy's `np.dot()` in contrast is more flexible; it computes the inner product for 1D arrays and performs matrix multiplication for 2D arrays.

[`torch.matmul`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.matmul) performs matrix multiplications if both arguments are `2D` and computes their dot product if both arguments are `1D`. For inputs of such dimensions, its behaviour is the same as `np.dot`. It also lets you do broadcasting or `matrix x matrix`, `matrix x vector` and `vector x vector` operations in batches.

```
# 1D inputs, same as torch.dot
a = torch.rand(n)
b = torch.rand(n)
torch.matmul(a, b) # torch.Size([])

# 2D inputs, same as torch.mm
a = torch.rand(m, k)
b = torch.rand(k, j)
torch.matmul(a, b) # torch.Size([m, j])
```

Comment: Since this is accepted answer, I think you should include torch.matmul. It performs dot product for 1D arrays and matrix multiplication for 2D arrays.

Answer (score 57):

To perform a matrix (rank 2 tensor) multiplication, use any of the following equivalent ways:

```
AB = A.mm(B)

AB = torch.mm(A, B)

AB = torch.matmul(A, B)

AB = A @ B  # Python 3.5+ only
```

There are a few subtleties. From the [PyTorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.mm):

> `torch.mm` does not broadcast. For broadcasting matrix products,
> see `torch.matmul()`.

For instance, you cannot multiply two 1-dimensional vectors with `torch.mm`, nor multiply batched matrices (rank 3). To this end, you should use the more versatile `torch.matmul`. For an extensive list of the broadcasting behaviours of `torch.matmul`, see the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.matmul).

For element-wise multiplication, you can simply do (if A and B have the same shape)

```
A * B  # element-wise matrix multiplication (Hadamard product)
```

Comment: I *love* the one-character `@` operator.  `w @ x` will be my goto

Comment: `torch.matmul` and `@` are equivalent only for a rank 2 tensor. The `@` operaion is "actually" `torch.bmm` (*b*atch *m*atrix *m*ultiply) in which the matrix multiply is done on the last two dimensions (https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-does-the-sign-work-in-this-instance/11232).

Answer (score 11):

Use `torch.mm(a, b)` or `torch.matmul(a, b)`
Both are same.

```
>>> torch.mm
<built-in method mm of type object at 0x11712a870>
>>> torch.matmul
<built-in method matmul of type object at 0x11712a870>
```

There's one more option that may be good to know.
That is `@` operator. @Simon H.

```
>>> a = torch.randn(2, 3)
>>> b = torch.randn(3, 4)
>>> a@b
tensor([[ 0.6176, -0.6743,  0.5989, -0.1390],
        [ 0.8699, -0.3445,  1.4122, -0.5826]])
>>> a.mm(b)
tensor([[ 0.6176, -0.6743,  0.5989, -0.1390],
        [ 0.8699, -0.3445,  1.4122, -0.5826]])
>>> a.matmul(b)
tensor([[ 0.6176, -0.6743,  0.5989, -0.1390],
        [ 0.8699, -0.3445,  1.4122, -0.5826]])
```

The three give the same results.

Related links:
[Matrix multiplication operator](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1)
[PEP 465 -- A dedicated infix operator for matrix multiplication](https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/)

Comment: Are `torch.mm(a,b)`, `torch.matmul(a,b)` and `a@b` equivalent? I can't find any documentation on the @ operator.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that there isn't any documentation about `@` operator. But, there are several notations in the document that include `@` in it that give the semantic of the matrix multiplication. So I think that the `@` operator has been overloaded by PyTorch in the meaning of matrix multiplication.

Comment: Added links to @ operator.

Answer (score 9):

You can use "@" for computing a dot product between two tensors in pytorch.

```
a = torch.tensor([[1,2],
                  [3,4]])
b = torch.tensor([[5,6],
                  [7,8]])
c = a@b #For dot product
c

d = a*b #For elementwise multiplication 
d
```