# Pytorch runtimeError "matrices expected, got 1D, 2D tensors at"

Tags: python, pytorch, runtime-error

I begin to practice Pytorch ，try to use torch.mm() method。

Below is my code

```
import torch 
import numpy as np
from torch.autograd import Variable
num_x = np.array([[1.0, 2.0]
                  ,[3.0,4.0]])

tensor_x = torch.from_numpy(num_x)
x = Variable(tensor_x,requires_grad = True)
s = Variable(torch.DoubleTensor([0.01,0.02]),requires_grad = True)
print(s)
s = s.mm(x)
print(s)
```

Unfortunately,there is a runtime error

```
*RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-e8a58ffb2545> in <module>()
      9 s = Variable(torch.DoubleTensor([0.01,0.02]),requires_grad = True)
     10 print(s)
---> 11 s = s.mm(x)
     12 print(s)
RuntimeError: matrices expected, got 1D, 2D tensors at /pytorch/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensorMath.cpp:131*
```

How can I fix this problem。
your reply is appreciated

Comment: are you trying to do matrix multiplication? Try reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44524901/how-to-do-product-of-matrices-in-pytorch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [`reshape`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.reshape) you need to change shape of `s` to `(1,2)` to make possible [matrix multiplication](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.mm) operation with `(2,2)` tensor

```py
>>> s.reshape(1,2).mm(x)
tensor([[0.0700, 0.1000]], dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<MmBackward>)
```

Or give right shape when initializing `s`

```py
>>> s = Variable(torch.DoubleTensor([[0.01,0.02]]),requires_grad = True)
>>> s.mm(x)
tensor([[0.0700, 0.1000]], dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<MmBackward>)
```

Answer (score 0):

or so:

```
>>> s @ x
tensor([0.0700, 0.1000], dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<SqueezeBackward3>)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or
why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.