# all pairwise dot product pytorch

Tags: pytorch, tensor, dot-product

Is there a built in function to calculate efficiently all pairwaise dot products of two tensors in Pytorch?
e.g.
input - tensor `A` (shape `N`x`D`)
tensor `B` (shape `N`x`D`)

output - tensor `C` (shape `N`x`N`) such that `C_i,j = torch.dot(A_i, B_j)` ?

Comment: Have you trired this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44524901/how-to-do-product-of-matrices-in-pytorch

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it simply

```py
C = torch.mm(A, B.T)  # same as C = A @ B.T
```

BTW,
A very flexible tool for matrix/vector/tensor dot products is [`torch.einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html#torch.einsum):

```py
C = torch.einsum('id,jd->ij', A, B)
```

Comment: Did you mean `torch.mm(A, B.T)`?

Comment: @Ivan is there a difference between `torch.mm`, `torch.bmm` and `torch.dot` for 2d tensors?

Comment: @Ivan one can always use the more general `torch.tensordot` and my personal favorite `torch.einsum`...

Comment: I believe `torch.dot` only works with 1D tensors. As for `torch.bmm`, it expects a *batch* axis, *i.e.* a third axis.

Comment: Do you know about the efficiency of `torch.einsum` *vs.* specific operators such as `torch.mm`, is it as good?